# Floating all images in a class

Tags: html, css, css-float

Exact instructions: Insert a style to float all img elements belonging to the irregularWrap class on the right margin, but only when the right margin is clear of other floating elements.

I'm not really sure what this question means? I get the float property but whats does it mean by only when the right margin is clear of other floating elements?

```
<img src="images/student1.jpg" alt="" class="irregularWrap">
<img src="images/student2.jpg" alt="" class="irregularWrap">  
<img src="images/student3.jpg" alt="" class="irregularWrap">
<img src="images/student4.jpg" alt="" class="irregularWrap">
<img src="images/student5.jpg" alt="" class="irregularWrap">
```

So those are the images, basically, its one images cut into 5 seperate pieces horizontally to make the words look like they kinda outline the image around the left edge.

The CSS I currently have is:

```
.irregularWrap { float: right; margin: 0px; }
```

I'm not sure if I'm just overthinking this due to my brain being fried trying to prepare for finals or if this is really just something we didn't quite cover. Any ideas where I'm messing up here?

[This is what all 5 images should look like when they come together as the one picture.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3km63.png)

[to clarify, this is what I'm getting with the 5 images, instead of them looking as they do in the previous image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y1QNT.png)

Comment: Perhaps the ``clear`` property will be useful:  https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#flow-control

Comment: so 5 images should be on top of each other and just show one?

Comment: yeah the stack on top of either other to create one, hence the 0px margins

Comment: Thank you chad! I had initially missed two things, the img.irregularWrap instead of .irregularWrap (maybe it doesn't matter) and the css link in the html file, I forgot i organized my style sheets into folders so i had to fix the link for the css to show up. I originally had the clear: right; in the css but took it out when i thought it didn't work, not realizing i just needed to fix the css link lol. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

In the CSS I needed to add

```
clear: right;
```

As I explained in a previous comment, I forgot to change the stylesheet link to include the folder on my html sheet so it was throwing my entire game off. Like I said, brain is probably fried. Lol.

Thanks for the help guys!

Answer (score -1):

You could try:

```
img {
    display:inline; // or inline-block;
}
```

Comment: This has nothing to do with the question.